# Format output to only include email

Tags: python, format

Total noob question IK
I need to remove "mailto:"
I only want [holtp@moval.edu] to be returned

```
def email_lookup(url):
    url_open =requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_open._content, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.find_all('a',{'class':'email'}):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

out put:

[mailto:holtp@moval.edu]

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that is using replace function:

```
link = link.replace("mailto:", "")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `replace(string_to_replace, new_string)` function to replace the substring you are wishing for.

So, you can use following code snippet:

```
string.replace('mailto:', '')
```

Comment: It looks like this is a duplicate of another answer that was posted earlier.

Comment: I was the first one that posted the answer.